# Find the remainder of $1^k+2^k+3^k+...+100^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the remainder of $1^k+2^k+3^k+...+100^k$ upon division by 4 where k is any odd integer bigger than 1

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2^{k}+4^{k}+6^{k}+\dots+100^{k} \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ from $k \ge 3$.

Also, note that for any $n$, $(4n+1)^{k}+(4n+3)^{k} \equiv 1^k+(-1)^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ 
Since $k$ is a odd number.

Thus, the answer is $0$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Seems odd to me, too. I've had that happen. Oh, well - I upvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

$1^k \equiv 1 \mod 4$

$2^k = 4*2^{k-1} \equiv 0 \mod 4$ if k>1

$3^k \equiv (-1)^k \ -1 \mod 4$ if k is odd

$0^k = 0 \mod 4$

In the numbers from 1 to 100 there are exactly 25 of each equivalences so remainder is $25 (1 +0 -1 +0) = 0 \mod 4$.  The remainder is 0 if k is odd and greater than 1.

If k=1 then $2 \equiv 2 \mod 4$ so remainder is $25 (1 +2 -1 + 0)=50 \equiv 2 \mod 4$ so remainder is 2.

If k is even $3^k \equiv  (-1)^k \equiv 1 \mod 4$ so $25 (1 + 2 -1 +0) = 50 \equiv 2 \mod 4$ has remainder 2.